# Create UIImageView in object

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a UIImageView programmatically in a method of a object.

```
-(void) createApple
{
  CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 64, 64);
  image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
  [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"]];
  [self.view addSubview:image];
  [image release]; 
}
```

when I use this code in the ViewController.m it works fine but when I use it in my Apple object I get an error:request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union.

What do I use instead of self.view???

Sorry if I'm repeating posts. I saw a similar question to this but wasn't sure if it was exactly the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line causing the error would be:

`[self.view addSubview:image];`

If your `Apple` object does not extend `UIViewController` then there will be so `self.view` property on it, unless you have defined one yourself.

As to what to use instead, that is difficult to say without knowing specifically what you are trying to do.

However, assuming that you want your `Apple` class to display something on the screen, then probably what you want to do is update `Apple` so that it extends either `UIViewController` or (perhaps) `UIView`.  Then in the first case you can use `self.view`, and in the second case you can just do `[self addSubview: image];`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am very new to OOP so don't quite get it yet.

Comment: Okay getting closer. I changed the Apple class to this:

Comment: Sorry I keep hitting Return - Doh. This is my first post. What a n00b. I changed the Apple class to this: @interface Apple : UIViewController and it no longer complains however no image appears. How do I make it a subclass?

Comment: @Kangoo - Using `@interface Apple : UIViewController` has made it a subclass.  To get the view to appear you need to either make `Apple` the active view controller, or add the view from `Apple` as a subview of the current UIViewController's view.

Comment: Okay great - how do I add the view from Apple as a subclass? Sorry to be a pain this is all new to me. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly you have an `interface` like this

```
@interface Apple: NSObject
@end
```

If you want to create an UIImageView using NSObject methods try this

```
//first declare a method of UIImageView type
@interface Apple: NSObject
{

}
-(UIImageView *)ImageView;
@end
```

now come in your `Apple.m` file

```
@implementation Apple

-(UIImageView *)ImageView
{
    UIImageView *imgView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 64, 64)];
    imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"];
    return imgView;
}
@end
```

now call this method where you want to show your image, in your ViewController.m file you can call it like this- You just have to import your object class first.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Apple.h"

@implementation ViewController
-(Void)ViewDidLoad
{
    Apple *appleObject = [Apple alloc]init];
    UIImageView *imageViewOfViewController = [appleObject ImageView];
    [self.view addSubView:imageViewOfViewController];
}
@end
```

I show you imageview method in viewDidLoad method you can call it any where like this.

Answer (score 0):

Because "view" is a property of UIViewController and your "apple object" doesn’t have one.

Comment: Yeah I thought so I just didn't know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, you're not calling this method inside UIViewController. Personally I'd do it slightly other way:

```
- (UIView*) newAppleView
{ 
  CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 64, 64);

  UIImageView *imageView;
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
  [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"]];

  return [imageView autorelease];
}
```

Assuming the **newAppleView** method is implemented in your UIViewController, you can easly add new apple:

```
[self.view addSubview:[self newAppleView]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I usually do do things that way but I'm trying to get my head around OOP so I'm experimenting with different approaches in the hope that I will learn something new conceptually.